# Создание вычисляемого столбца : определение общего признака по уже существующим

Tags: python, pandas, функции

Есть следующая таблица :

| Заказ | Статус |
| --- | --- |
| Заказ 1 | корректный |
| Заказ 1 | корректный |
| Заказ 1 | не корректный |
| Заказ 2 | корректный |
| Заказ 2 | корректный |
| Заказ 3 | не корректный |

не могу понять, как правильно написать функцию, которая создаст новый вычисляемый столбец "Общий статус", в котором для одинаковых заказов в каждой строке должен быть определен общий статус по условию из столбца "Статус".

Логика такая, если у заказа есть хотя бы один статус "не корректный" в столбце "Статус", то для всех записей данного заказа в таблице должен быть определен статус "не корректный", то что должно получиться на выходе :

| Заказ | Статус | Общий статус |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Заказ 1 | корректный | не корректный |
| Заказ 1 | корректный | не корректный |
| Заказ 1 | не корректный | не корректный |
| Заказ 2 | корректный | корректный |
| Заказ 2 | корректный | корректный |
| Заказ 3 | не корректный | не корректный |

Написал следующий код, но он работает не корректно

```
import pandas as pd

orders = {'Заказ': ['Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1',
'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 3'],
'Статус': ['корректный', 'корректный',
'не корректный', 'корректный',
'корректный', 'не корректный']}

data = pd.DataFrame(orders)

# Создаем новый столбец
data['Общий статус'] = ''


def create_order_status(data): 
    for i in range(len(data)): 
        if data.loc[i,'Статус'] =='некорректный': 
            data.loc[i:, 'Общий статус'] ='некорректный' 
        else: 
            data.loc[i:, 'Общий статус'] =data.loc[i, 'Статус']  
    return data 

data=create_order_status(data)
display(data)
```

Comment: Добавьте метку [pandas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Группируем по заказу и применяем к каждой группе метод `transform()`, который заменяет все значения из столбца Статус на максимальное значение из него же (по каждой группе заказов).  Так как буква 'н' больше буквы 'к', то при наличии хотя бы одного вхождения 'не корректный', все значения в группе станут такими.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Заказ': ['Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1', 'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 3'], 'Статус': ['корректный', 'корректный', 'не корректный', 'корректный', 'корректный', 'не корректный']})
df['Общий статус'] = df.groupby('Заказ').transform(max)
print(df)
```

```
     Заказ         Статус   Общий статус
0  Заказ 1     корректный  не корректный
1  Заказ 1     корректный  не корректный
2  Заказ 1  не корректный  не корректный
3  Заказ 2     корректный     корректный
4  Заказ 2     корректный     корректный
5  Заказ 3  не корректный  не корректный
```

Решение можно сделать более гибким (управляемым) и мощным, если категорий больше 2 и/или неудобно устанавливать "старшинство" статусов исходя из алфавита. Тогда применяем категории:

```
order = ['корректный', 'не корректный', 'специальный']  # чем правее элемент, тем он "старше"
df = pd.DataFrame({'Заказ': ['Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1', 'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 3'], 'Статус': ['корректный', 'корректный', 'не корректный', 'не корректный', 'специальный', 'не корректный']})
df['Статус'] = df['Статус'].astype("category").cat.reorder_categories(order, ordered=True)
df['Общий статус'] = df.groupby('Заказ').transform(max)
print(df)
```

```
     Заказ         Статус   Общий статус
0  Заказ 1     корректный  не корректный
1  Заказ 1     корректный  не корректный
2  Заказ 1  не корректный  не корректный
3  Заказ 2  не корректный    специальный
4  Заказ 2    специальный    специальный
5  Заказ 3  не корректный  не корректный
```

В этом примере выстроена иерархия статусов `order`- перечислены все статусы слева направо - чем правее, тем старше. Так, если в группе есть только `корректный`, то все будут такие. Если среди статусов `корректный`, есть хотя бы один `не корректный`, то все станут `не корректный`. Если в группе есть и `корректный` и `не корректный` и `специальный`, то все статусы станут `специальный`, поскольку `специальный` самый "старший"

**Отдельно** - в качестве отрицательного примера - как можно было бы сделать ваш код рабочим (**не делайте так**):

```
orders = {'Заказ': ['Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1', 'Заказ 1',
                    'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 2', 'Заказ 3'],
          'Статус': ['корректный', 'корректный',
                     'не корректный', 'корректный',
                     'корректный', 'не корректный']}

data = pd.DataFrame(orders)

# Создаем новый столбец
data['Общий статус'] = ''


def create_order_status(data):  # так делать не нужно, это криво и неэффективно
    zakazy = data['Заказ'].drop_duplicates()  # делаем Series с уникальными названиями заказов
    for _, value in zakazy.items():  # итерируем по уникальным названиям заказов (перебираем группы заказов)
        mask = data['Заказ'].eq(value)  # формируем булев массив - маску - для очередной группы с уникальным названием заказа
        if len(data[mask & data['Статус'].eq('не корректный')]):  # фильтруем очередную группу на предмет, есть ли хоть одно значение  'не корректный'
            data.loc[mask, 'Общий статус'] = 'не корректный'  # если есть, присваиваем всей группе 'не корректный'
        else:
            data.loc[mask, 'Общий статус'] = 'корректный'  # если нет, то все в группе - 'корректный'
    return data


data = create_order_status(data)
print(data)
```

```
     Заказ         Статус   Общий статус
0  Заказ 1     корректный  не корректный
1  Заказ 1     корректный  не корректный
2  Заказ 1  не корректный  не корректный
3  Заказ 2     корректный     корректный
4  Заказ 2     корректный     корректный
5  Заказ 3  не корректный  не корректный
```

Пояснения - что не так было в исходном коде:

1. Не было группировок по заказам - вместо этого рассматривались строки с i-й до конца фрейма.
2. Сравнивался статус 'не корректный' со значением 'некорректный', в итоге результат сравнения - всегда False. Т.е. в цикле фрейм не мог поменяться никогда, и из функции возвращался всегда исходный фрейм.
3. Вместо `print()` использовалась функция `display()`, которая не определена в коде, что вызывало ошибку `NameError: name 'display' is not defined`.

Comment: спасибо, работает ! я понимаю, что решение предложенное Вами минимальное и лаконичное, но можете подсказать именно по моей функции, что не так, чтобы понимать как можно решать подобные задачи с помощью функции ?

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ ! Это дополнение еще более "продвинутое" относительно моего первоначального варианта

Comment: Еще раз спасибо ! возьму Ваши комментарии и рекомендации на вооружение в свои будущие проекты